# valgrind invalid read of size 4, where is the error?

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm new with valgrind and I'm trying to use it for memory leaks and other memory problems. In my program I have defined the following class

```
class LM_EXPORT LdpElement : public Visitable, virtual public RefCounted,
                             public NodeInTree<LdpElement>
{
protected:
    ELdpElement m_type;     // the element type
    std::string m_name;     // for composite: element name
    std::string m_value;    // for simple: the element value
    bool m_fSimple;         // true for simple elements
    int m_numLine;          // file line in which the element starts or 0
    long m_id;              // for composite: element ID (0..n)
    ImoObj* m_pImo;

    LdpElement();

public:
    virtual ~LdpElement();

    //getters and setters
    ...
    inline ImoObj* get_imo() { return m_pImo; }
```

Valgrind is complaining in this last line "invalid read of size 4". Why? Where is the memory problem in returning the pointer?

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer without *actual* valgrind output. The problem is most certainly *not* on the last line, but elsewhere.

Comment: You were right. The problem disappeared after solving other memory issues. Sorry for not having answered earlier. I saw your answers yesterday, and returned to try solving Valgrid issues. You advice was the key for solving this. Thank you.

Comment: This is a good question, yet there are no answeres.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `m_pImo` isn't initialized and valgrind doesn't like that? Does the implementation of your constructor have an initialization list that initializes `m_pImo`?

Comment: Returning uninitialized value does *not* trigger valgrind error. Please refrain from giving bogus answers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now everyone that didn't know has learned something new. I won't however refrain from posting suggestions that are based on reasonable assumptions such as uninitialized data. That's what up/down votes are for. If my suggestion is ever so wrong that it is potentially harmful, I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

At a high very level, and not necessarily always the cause, I have seen that sometimes Valgrind will complain so when your final (debug) binary (executable) has more than one symbol in it (when linker option is set to be false for "dead code stripping").

I hope this will help others in future. I just discovered this after wasting 2 hours on it. :(